# Почему psql не открывает URL-адрес?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Часто в OS X использую вот такую команду:

```
$ psql postgres://[user]:[passsword]@[domain]:[port]/[database]
```

Но вот недавно на сервере с CentOS все классически поставил и настроил PostgreSQL, но клиент к БД категорически не работает с URL, в документации никак не смог найти информацию по тому как psql заставить работать с URL адресами.

Подскажите как сделать настройку, чтобы клиент принимал URL вместо вот таких длинных команд:

```
$ psql -h [domain] -p [port] -U [user] -w [database]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man psql (у меня версия 9.4)

```
   An alternative way to specify connection parameters is in a conninfo
   string or a URI, which is used instead of a database name. This
   mechanism give you very wide control over the connection. For example:

       $ psql "service=myservice sslmode=require"
       $ psql postgresql://dbmaster:5433/mydb?sslmode=require

   This way you can also use LDAP for connection parameter lookup as
   described in Section 31.17, "LDAP Lookup of Connection Parameters", in
   the documentation. See Section 31.1.2, "Parameter Key Words", in the
   documentation for more information on all the available connection
   options.
```

Comment: Да, видимо все упирается в версию psql.